# Выбрать последнюю запись для каждого ID

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть таблица

```
ID  COMMAND
523 "Расписание"
523 "Анекдот"
523 "Шутка"
123 "Анекдот"
123 "Вверх"
```

Никак не могу сделать запрос, чтобы по итогу вывелась последняя команда для каждого ID т.е. вывод будет:

```
ID  COMMAND
523 "Шутка"
123 "Вверх"
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: А почему "последней" считается именно "Штука" и "Вверх" ? Ведь в sql нет понятия порядка строк до тех пока не задан явный порядок в order by. Так вот что указать в order by, что бы последние были в конце ?

Comment: А все, тогда понял как решить проблему